# Laravel transactions for swapping rows

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with columns, one of them is `id`.

```
+-------+                 +-------+
|    id |                 |    id |
+-------+                 +-------+
|     1 |            \    |     5 |
|     2 |   --------- \   |     3 |
|     3 |   --------- /   |     2 |
|     4 |            /    |     1 |
|     5 |                 |     4 |
|     6 |                 |     6 |
+-------+                 +-------+
```

I want to swap `id` values of row in such a way that, if any of the step fails it must rollback, and `id` is currently set as *unique* constraint. How to use transactions **in Laravel** to swap these `id` values? I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You start by wrapping your database operations in a transaction closure, like so:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::table('users')->update(['name' => 'Billy Bob']);

    DB::table('posts')->delete();
});
```

You are going to run into trouble though with duplicate collisions when setting the primary key field id if the column you are swapping with contains any matching values in the current id column.

You may be better off creating a new temporary table with the id's from the desired column, populating it with the rest of the existing tables data, dropping that table and then recreating it with your temporary one.

Also, are they any other tables which have references to this table? Changing keys could cause havoc if that's the case.

Comment: I think it is not efficient to create another temporary table. Is there any way to remove unique without using Schema fascade and then add unique back?

Comment: It is possible `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY`. How often are you doing this that would concern you with efficiency anyway?

Comment: ah forgot about the raw queries :) I will try that. Regarding efficiency: there can be a huge number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can make trasaction using this,

```
DB::transaction(function() {
      // your code goes here 
});
```

Everything inside the `Closure executes within a transaction`. 
If anything wrong occurs it will rollback automatically.